# VHDL: Using type 'time' in generic map

Tags: generics, vhdl

I have a generated unit, which uses generics of type 'time'. When I try to map these generics, my simulator croaks during elaboration with the message: 'illegal generic map aspect'. Is it illegal to have a generic map like this?

```
inst: mod_name
generic map (
   delay_val => 12 ns
)
...
```

or is just my simulator not able to cope with this?

Note: As the unit is generated code, I can't just change the type to integer and do some casting inside. Such changes would be overwritten each time, the code is generated anew, which happens from time to time.

Comment: if `delay_val` really is type time, then there is nothing wrong with this. What simulator wont have it? any chance of more code and what the full error is?

Comment: The generic map looks fine to me. The only thing that springs to mind is if any of your generics are named `delay_length` then that _might_ confuse a simulator because `delay_length` is a standard VHDL type. Otherwise, please post the full code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As I can't post the full code here, I made a small example, which compiles without any problems. So it is a tool problem, not a VHDL problem and I'll have to contact my tool vendor. I'll post the code as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

A small test case for this "problem" looks like this. But this compiles without any warning or error message. So this is perfectly valid VHDL (as expected) and my issue is a tool problem, that I have to deal with my tool vendor.

Sub-Module:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity clk_gen is
  generic (
    clk_period : time := 10 ns
  );
  port (
    clk : out std_logic
  );
end clk_gen;

architecture beh of clk_gen is
  signal clk_int : std_logic := '0';
begin  -- beh

  clk <= clk_int;
  
  ckg: process
  begin
    clk_int <= not clk_int;
    wait for clk_period/2;
  end process ckg;
  
end beh;
```

Test bench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb_clk_gen is
  -- empty
end tb_clk_gen;

architecture beh of tb_clk_gen is
  signal clk : std_logic;
begin  -- beh

  ckg: entity work.clk_gen(beh)
    generic map (
      clk_period => 12 ns
    )
    port map (
      clk => clk
    );

end beh;
```

Comment: I'd argue it is more likely a code problem if this compiled in the same tool without error.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The code that didn't compile was originally generated by another tool. I added the generic map at the instantiation of the module, which was 'old style' using a component declaration in the architecture declarative section and a (default) configuration mapping. I missed out the fact, that the component declaration didn't have the generics section, it only had the ports section.